# A single smartphone-compatible (iPhone, Blackberry, Android) mobile version for a Rails app?

Tags: iphone, android

So I just learned about jQTouch and others (PhoneGap?) and there seems to be great work being done in this space.  I have a Rails app and would like a single production-quality mobile version that will work across the aforementioned platforms (and others?), with minimal extra development work.

Answer (score 0):

You say you have a Rails app.  So you already have a webapp, and you just want the same app on several phone platforms?  Why not just make sure your webapp works on mobile browsers?

Comment: Thanks mbaird.  Might have phrased the question badly, that's exactly what I want to do and was wondering if there were templates and such that would help me do this so the mobile version showed up nicely across all phones.

Comment: Ah, when you asked about PhoneGap it sounded like you where looking to make an actual native app for different phones, which is what that does.  If you just want your webapp to look good on mobile browsers, I'd do a search for "mobile CSS".  That search turns up tons of hits on google and on StackOverflow.  You might also want to ask a new question, something like "how do I get started making a mobile friendly version of my website".  From what I understand you will probably just need to make a different set of CSS files that are used when mobile devices view your site.